Como puedo monitorear cuantas veces se usa,lanza o abre un software en windows con Python
Buenas noches a toda la comunidad, disculpen si estamos iniciando en este mundo Python; quisiera saber si con código de Python puedo saber cuantas veces se inicia, lanza o abre un software específico; existe alguna librería que me recomieden. Gracias por sus respuestas.

Tal como está redactada, básicamente estás pidiendo que te hagan la aplicación desde cero (porque no hay otra forma de responderla que hacer eso), además no se permiten preguntas que pidan recomendaciones y por último python no es programación de bajo nivel

Para no dejarte tan en el aire, te comento que lo más probable es que desde python debas consultar a windows (mediante un comando) por el proceso en ejecución. Te recomiendo investigar: Process Monitor, tasklist /NH | findstr /I nombreproceso.exe y WMIC PROCESS where (Name='nombreproceso.exe'). Seguramente alguno de ellos te puede ayudar a empezar

Hola mymarcosweb, si entiendo bien lo que necesitas, puedes hacer un script que lance el programa en cuestión, y lea e incremente ell valor adecuado en un archivo.

Muchas gracias a todos por sus alcances.

Puedes hacer wrapper que lleve la cuenta y lance la aplicación.
